# Is my CPU average Temperature fine?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, cooling, temperature

I am using Asus-KS3SD, which is known for its ice cool behavior, but these days I noticed my Palm rest is getting warm, even if I run few programs like Browser+IDM+some little programs. I used Speccy to monitor the temperature and it is around 65 C - 70 C. It is Hot summer out here and the temperature outside is above 40 C. So I am just worried is my laptop getting overheated

These are the specs of my Lappy:

- Intel Core i3 2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Nvidia GetForce 610M 2GB GPU and Intel HD Graphics 3000
- 4GB RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it could always run cooler. The max temp seems to be 85. If you're worried about it, try cleaning out the fans with compressed air or getting one of those laptop cooling pads.

Source: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i3/Intel-Core%20i3%20Mobile%20i3-2350M.html

Answer (score 1):

Laptop temperatures usually run a bit higher than your average Desktop, mostly due to the lack of of airflow and fanspeeds. However, that said, your temperatures sound a bit high. Even with the 40 C temperatures outside.

I suggest using compressed air (as @user159726 already mentioned). If your laptop is a few months to a year old, you simply could have dust piling up and the fans don't get the airflow going properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have corei3 too, If you use Linux, you can see your temp with `sensors` command.

It says: **(high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)**

Then don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CPU average Temperature fine?
Yes, but it may damage your hardware especially CPU in long run.

How old is your laptop? 
For new laptops, it should be around or under 50C at normal use. (normally 10 C above your environment temperature.)

For old ones, you can do nothing but clean your CPU fan. If you never did it before, it will work surprisingly well.

My old Sumsung laptop which is 4 years old was around 70C before cleanning and now it is 60C at normal use. (yours should not be as hot as mine..)

Comment: mine is just 1 year old :( ... but it is always about 60C even at 40C room temperature